# C# struct or struct[] as member of struct contiguous in memory

Tags: c#, memory, struct, memory-management

I am trying to understand how having a struct as a member of a struct would be stored in memory. From what I understand, if we had a simple struct in memory, for example

```
struct Simple {
  int x;
  bool y;
}
```

then in if we initialized `Simple s = new Simple()` in memory we would see something contiguous like

```
s(0x01) --> 0x01(x - 32 bits data, y - 32 bits data)
```

so if we called `s.x` then we would need to fetch `s` into the cpu and then have access to both x and y for operations since they are contiguous.

Now if we had an array of structs as a member

```
struct Simple {
  int x;
  Other[] otherArray;

  Simple(int input, Other[] otherInput)
  {
    x = input;
    otherArray = otherInput;
  }
}

struct Other {
  bool y;
}
```

if we did `Simple s = new Simple()` then in memory we would have

```
s(0x01) --> 0x01(x - 32 bits, otherArray - 64 bit reference type)
```

`s.otherArray[0]` would need to be fetched separately wherever it is stored in memory. This is because the actual values within `otherArray` are not contiguously stored with `x` but the reference to the data is contiguous after `x`. If `otherArray` is initialized as `Simple s = new Simple(1, new Simple[1])`, would `otherArray` data be stored contiguously after x or is `otherArray` always going to be a reference type either way (whether it's initialized in the struct constructor or not)?

Finally, if we have a struct as a member of a struct

```
struct Simple {
  int x;
  Other other;
}
```

this is where it is unclear for me. Is `Simple s = new Simple()` now stored as

```
s(0x01) --> 0x01(x - 32 bits data, other - 32 bits data of y as bool)
```

or is it

```
s(0x01) --> 0x01(x - 32 bits, other - some reference to the data containing y as bool)
```

In other words, is a struct as a member of struct stored contiguously with the struct or is it simply stored as some sort of address to the actual data of the other struct?

I would also appreciate any correction to my logic or further knowledge on how different types are stored in memory within struct as I am trying to generally understand how C# stores data in memory, thank you

Comment: Other is a pointer to where rest of data is located.  In c# the struct is wrapped because c# is managed to prevent exceptions when a null address is found.  In straight c language there is no wrapper so other is a pointer but may be the address followint other.  The wrapper in c# as other internal bytes that you do not see.

Comment: @jdweng Really? I've found the opposite by reading the struct's contents using `Marshal.ReadInt64` though. Another observation is that when the size of `Other` grows, The size of `Simple` grows as well.

Comment: SharpLab's `Inspect.Stack` shows them as one continuous combined object. And `Unsafe.SizeOf` increases/decreases appropriately. See this sharplab (and uncomment the two commented lines) https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AJWmAEsBbAU0oGEB7RgB3oBtmYAMqCAbvQDGzAM4BuPHgCSUad2YTglIcACGEgNYAKKMwDupIU24DDASgDeeUs9IB1ALwBmGE5cANdxNTO0dcF3DSAE13AFYYUl8IgHok0gAtdwAWRNIAXzxc23l8AgBOQwBVFR0AM1ZLAC9mAHkagB5LHgEAPjsihVxpYEgNCysBUlDw1E9SeihgN2Lp2ebgAAtBUj9l51yEweGIUbXNsEmDlbmFqN3nFJnrxbTi/aA==

Comment: @Sweeper : Did you verify what you observed using sizeof()?

Comment: @jdweng Yes, and it shows that `other` is not a pointer.

Comment: @Sweeper : Are you using the last version of the struct which is what the question is asking?

Comment: @jdweng I would think so... It's the `struct Simple { int x; Other other; }` version, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would `otherArray` data be stored contiguously after `x` or is `otherArray` always going to be a reference type either way

`otherArray` is always going to be a *reference* to an array object, even if it only has one element. The struct layout is a property of the struct type, not a property of particular struct values.

> is a struct as a member of struct stored contiguously with the struct or is it simply stored as some sort of address to the actual data of the other struct?

Structs are value types, so there is no "some sort of address to the actual data of the other struct". That's what reference types would do. It's not contiguous necessarily, (but it is contiguous in the case of `Other` and `Simple`) - it will follow the default alignment rules if you don't specify an explicit `Pack` or `LayoutKind`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=net-5.0) for more info.

Let's consider:

```
struct Simple
{
    public int x;
    public Other other;
}

struct Other
{
    public int y;
}
```

and the value:

```
var s = new Simple();
s.x = unchecked((int)0xabcdefab);
s.other.y = 0x12345678;
```

You'd expect the size of `s` be 8 bytes, and its value will contain the numbers `0xabcdefab` and `0x12345678`:

```
// prints 8
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(Simple));
// in an unsafe block, prints 12345678ABCDEFAB
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.ReadInt64(new IntPtr(&s)).ToString("X"));
```

You can try adding more fields to `Other`, and see that `sizeof(Simple)` increases

Compare this to a reference type:

```
struct Simple
{
    public int x;
    public OtherRef other;
}

class OtherRef
{
    public int y;
}
```

You can't use `&` to get the address now, so here's a [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AJWmAEsBbAU0oGEB7RgB3oBtmYAMqCAbvQDGzAM4BuPHgCSUad2YTglIcACGEgNYAKKMwDupIU24DDASgDeeUs9IAPALwBmGE5cdgABaC7iamdo64LlGkAJ7uAKy+zgC+eMm28vgEAJyGAKoqOgBmrJYAXswA8kUAPJY8AgB8dhkKkS7SwJAaFlYCSaQR0S6onqT0UMBumcPOo6SVgYLUzEWk/kFgMy6puAMYC0tgK0UDQ7PzE1Mx2ylAA) link to show that the `other` field is indeed an address, rather than the value you set it.